# Logging / Tracking CRUD operations in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, log4net, crud, tracking

I want to save all of the CRUD operations with the user's detail to the database and then monitor these info according to the following approach below. In my opinion, the second approach seems better so that it can be managed from one specific table and can also be used for the critical info. So, could you please clarify me by giving an applicable example on how to perform this best in both cases with a framework or a custom code that is suitable for MVC5 and MsSQL Server? Thanks in advance.

**Approach I:** By adding "CreatedBy", "CreatedOn", etc. columns to the related tables and add/update the info ("CreatedBy", "CreatedOn", etc.) on these tables whenever a records is added or updated. In that case only the last update info will be obtained from the database and the prior operations cannot be obtained.


**Approach II:** By creating a new table in the database and add a new record for every CRUD operation containing "CreatedBy", "CreatedOn", "Controller", "Action", "Record Id", "Upadte Value", and the other necessary fields.

Comment: use triggers in sql.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it can be used also. But I would like to use a method on program side instead of database side.

Comment: so you want to insert records into DB when an entity changes?

Comment: Yes, the second approach seems better. So, when a user add a record then another method will be called even after the SaveRecord() in order to add all the necessary user info and all the necessary action info to the Tracking table.

Comment: why you need to call the DB twice for a Insert method ?

Comment: You are right, but it is common approach and I do not want to use database trigger :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found Bilal Fazlani's perfect article "[Adding Log Feature to Entity Framework](http://bilal-fazlani.blogspot.in/2013/09/adding-log-audit-feature-to-entity.html)" and that is really very easy to integrate to the project. Anyone who need to log/audit in Entity Framework by using Code First approach easily apply it to their own project. Thanks a lot for your help...

Answer (score 2):

We use Approach 1 in all of our solutions:

```
public partial class Database
{
    public Database(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, true)
    {
        CurrentUser = "SYSTEM";
    }

    public string CurrentUser
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries();

        if (changeSet != null)
        {
            foreach (var change in changeSet.Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
            {
                if (change.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    SetCreatedFields(change);
                    SetLastChangedFields(change);
                }
                if (change.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    SetLastChangedFields(change);
                }

            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void SetLastChangedFields(DbEntityEntry change)
    {
        var entity = change.Entity as dynamic;
        entity.LastChangedBy= !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUser) ? CurrentUser : "System";
        entity.LastChanged = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void SetCreatedFields(DbEntityEntry change)
    {
        var entity = change.Entity as dynamic;
        entity.CreatedBy = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUser) ? CurrentUser : "System";
        entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
    }    
}
```

I realize it's not very good practice to use `dymanic` but it's simple and it works.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In that case do you add some columns regarding to tracking data (i.e. updatedBy, updatedOn) to each of the related tables? Or do you create a new table for adding tracking info?

Comment: All my tables have those columns.

Comment: In that case should I follow the following steps? Could you check and clarify me before I proceed? 1) Adding CreatedBy and Created columns to   all of the related tables. 2) Updating my CRUD class as above? 3) If there is an extra steps please type here. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Just edit the SaveChanges code to match your property names

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It is really very good approach to override SaveChanges(). However, when applying your code above, I encounter an error on   foreach (var change in changeSet.Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged)) line (due to "Where"). On the other hand, when looking to solve this problem I run into a more complex solution containing version and adding changes to another table on this page: 
http://lourenco.co.za/blog/2013/07/audit-trails-concurrency-and-soft-deletion-with-entity-framework/  I could apply it, but there is a little problem regarding to this solution. >>>

Comment: >>> One of them is that it uses a new table, but the columns on that table does not enough to obtain which changes are made on which table. Could you have a look at this solution and update only the code block below the "//Do audit trails" class in" section so that it can add the necessary changes to the same entity instead of new table? Now I voted up your answer due to the fact that it give an idea to override SaveChanges() method even if it does not work. I will mark as answer after your code changes. Thanks for your help.